# Is there a general way to calculate sectional curvature of a given Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold (M,g) which is the best way to calculate the Riemannian tensor, the Ricci tensor, the sectional curvatures, the principle curvature (and so on) of the Riemannian manifold?
Does it depend on the way the Riemannian manifold is given? I mean if it's given as a submanifold of an ambient space or by a parametrization?

Comment: The title of your question asks for "general" but the body asks for "best". These are not the same thing. For a general method: use the definitions of these curvature tensors which you find in (any) textbook.  But sometimes one can do better than this.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you give me a particular example in which different methods work better?

Comment: Principal curvature only makes sense for a hypersurface (or, more generally, a submanifold of higher codimension), but not for an abstract Riemannian manifold. One particular example where everything follows from the algebraic structure is that of Lie groups and their homogeneous space quotients. Also, the answer(s) to your question(s) depend on what mathematical structures you're good at calculating with — differential forms versus vector fields, etc.